# Serial port or USB port using D?

Tags: usb, serial-port, d

I'm new using the D programming language and I was wondering if D can make use of the Serial port or usb port?

Answer (score 6):

That would presumably involve system calls of some kind, which would be in C, but you can [call C functions from D](http://d-programming-language.org/interfaceToC.html), so unless there's a library that will wrap it for you (which I rather doubt), you'll have to figure out what the appropriate C calls are and use them.

Answer (score 5):

Creating bindings to C libraries is pretty straightforward in D, so you might try [libusb](http://www.libusb.org/) for cross-system USB access.

Comment: Link to official documentation (with examples) for "Interfacing to C" in D Language: https://dlang.org/spec/interfaceToC.html

Answer (score 1):

Tango can do Serial port. Please refer to

- [tango.io.device.SerialPort](http://siegelord.github.com/Tango-D2/tango.io.device.SerialPort.html) module
- [tango.io.device.Device.Device](http://siegelord.github.com/Tango-D2/htmlsrc/tango.io.device.SerialPort.html#L45) class

Please notice that the URLs refers to a D2 port of Tango.